# Spark Scala - compile errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-zeppelin

I have a script in scala, when I run it in Zeppelin works well, but when I try compile with sbt, it doesnt work. I believe is something related to the versions but Im not being able to identify.

Those three ways returns the same error:

```
val catMap = catDF.rdd.map((row: Row) => (row.getAs[String](1)->row.getAs[Integer](0))).collect.toMap
val catMap = catDF.select($"description", $"id".cast("int")).as[(String, Int)].collect.toMap
val catMap = catDF.rdd.map((row: Row) => (row.getAs[String](1)->row.getAs[Integer](0))).collectAsMap()
```

Returning an error: "value rdd is not a member of Unit"

```
val bizCat = bizCatRDD.rdd.map(t => (t.getAs[String](0),catMap(t.getAs[String](1)))).toDF
```

Returning an error: "value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]"

Scala version: 2.12
Sbt Version: 1.3.13

**UPDATE:**
The whole class is:
package importer

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}

import org.apache.spark.sql._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import udf.functions._

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

object BusinessImporter extends Importer{

    def importa(spark: SparkSession, inputDir: String): Unit = {
        
        import spark.implicits._
        val bizDF = spark.read.json(inputDir).cache

        // categories
        val explode_categories = bizDF.withColumn("categories", explode(split(col("categories"), ",")))
        val sort_categories = explode_categories.select(col("categories").as("description"))
                .distinct
                .coalesce(1)
                .orderBy(asc("categories"))
        // Create sequence column
        val windowSpec = Window.orderBy("description")
        val categories_with_sequence = sort_categories.withColumn("id",row_number.over(windowSpec))
        val categories = categories_with_sequence.select("id","description")

        val catDF = categories.write.insertInto("categories")

        // business categories
        //val catMap = catDF.rdd.map((row: Row) => (row.getAs[String](1)->row.getAs[Integer](0))).collect.toMap
        //val catMap = catDF.select($"description", $"id".cast("int")).as[(String, Int)].collect.toMap
        val catMap = catDF.rdd.map((row: Row) => (row.getAs[String](1)->row.getAs[Integer](0))).collectAsMap()
        val auxbizCatRDD = bizDF.withColumn("categories", explode(split(col("categories"), ",")))
        val bizCatRDD = auxbizCatRDD.select("business_id","categories")
        val bizCat = bizCatRDD.rdd.map(t => (t.getAs[String](0),catMap(t.getAs[String](1)))).toDF
        bizCat.write.insertInto("business_category")

        // Business
        val businessDF = bizDF.select("business_id","categories","city","address","latitude","longitude","name","is_open","review_count","stars","state")
        businessDF.coalesce(1).write.insertInto("business")

        // Hours
        val bizHoursDF = bizDF.select("business_id","hours.Sunday","hours.Monday","hours.Tuesday","hours.Wednesday","hours.Thursday","hours.Friday","hours.Saturday")

        val bizHoursDF_structs = bizHoursDF
            .withColumn("Sunday",struct(
            split(col("Sunday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Sunday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Monday",struct(
            split(col("Monday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Monday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Tuesday",struct(
            split(col("Tuesday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Tuesday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Wednesday",struct(
            split(col("Wednesday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Wednesday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Thursday",struct(
            split(col("Thursday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Thursday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Friday",struct(
            split(col("Friday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Friday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))
            .withColumn("Saturday",struct(
            split(col("Saturday"),"-").getItem(0).as("Open"),
            split(col("Saturday"),"-").getItem(1).as("Close")))

        bizHoursDF_structs.coalesce(1).write.insertInto("business_hour")
        
    }

    def singleSpace(col: Column): Column = {
        trim(regexp_replace(col, " +", " "))
    }
}
```

sbt file:

```
name := "yelp-spark-processor"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.12" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.12"  % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.12" % "3.0.1"
```

Can someone pls give me some orientations about what is wrong?

Many Thanks
Xavy

Comment: How did you create `bizCatRDD` ?

Comment: What does your build file look like?

Comment: Hi all, I updated the post to show the whole class  and the sbt file.
Many Thanks Xavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that in scala this line returns type Unit:

```
val catDF = categories.write.insertInto("categories")
```

Unit in scala is like void in java, it's returned by functions that don't return anything meaningful. So basically at this point catDF is not a dataframe and you can't treat it as such. So you probably want to keep using `categories` instead of `catDF` in the lines that follow.

Comment: Many Thanks. Worked perfectly and solved my issue. I'm doing the baby steps with Scala and Spark. So the basic questions/issues sometimes happen

Comment: Glad to hear that, happy to help. You might want to look into proper Scala IDE:s like IntelliJ IDEA, they will help you a lot with this kind of issues.